# Nginx отдать простой html файл

Tags: nginx

Вообщем хочу отдавать статический html в случае неподдерживаемого браузера. Вот пример [конфига](https://gist.github.com/joelmoss/233840) . Как отдать чисто файл, не ридерект, просто файл

```
if ($unsupported_browser_rewrite = perform){
  **** /full/path/to/html/file.html; - что написать?
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if ($unsupported_browser_rewrite = perform){
  rewrite ^ /unsupported_browser.html;
  break;
}

Comment: Не понял?  "/unsupported_browser.html" первый слеш это не файловая система это урл ...

Comment: да, http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

Comment: Вопрос вродь в том, чтобы путь относительно файловой системы, а не "урла" ...

Comment: другого способа насколько я знаю нет.

Comment: А может именованный location?

Comment: может быть как-то так:

if ($unsupported_browser_rewrite = perform){ rewrite ^ /unsupported_browser; break; }

location /unsupported_browser_rewrite {
  index file.html;
  alias /full/path/to/html;
}